# Opening Series of Gifs in Chrome Using webbrowser

Tags: python, browser, gif

I have a series of local gif files. I was wondering how I would be able to open this series of local gifs using the webbrowser module. I am, by the way, running on Mac OS X Snow Leapord. Whenever I try to use the webbrowser.open('file:gif_name') snippet, my computer throws the error 0:30: execution error: Bad name for file. some object (-37). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you use `file://gif_name` instead?

Comment: Hmm... very strange. It opens a Firefox window (my default is Chrome) with my root directory listed. Perhaps I must list the FULL path?

Comment: I think so...use `os.getcwd()` to get your current path.

Comment: webbrowser.open('file://'+os.getcwd()+'/gif_name.gif')

Comment: This line of code opens a Preview window for some strange reason?

Comment: How about making Chrome the default app to view pictures? I think the current default is Preview.

Comment: Thanks so much. Post a reply, and I'll be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this line: `webbrowser.open('file://'+os.getcwd()+'/gif_name.gif')` and change the default app to view pictures to Chrome.